# intitializing if statments,variables and arrays in class

Tags: java

i am trying to do something very simple but i keep getting identifier errors. i want to initialize a variable, a if statement and an array within a class, this is a much simpler version of my own maze program that i am showing you to illustrate the basic code setup.what am i doing wrong if anyone could show me how to write the code so the compiler wont give me errors that would be great, thank you very much

```
public class mazet{

     public static void main(String a[]){

         class square {

             boolean sides[]=new boolean[]{true, false, false, false};
              int topx,topy,rightx,righty,downx,downy,leftx,lefty;

             if (sides[0]=false);
             {
             topx=0;
         }
             else if (sides[0]=true);
             {
                     topx= 40;
         }


     }}
```

Comment: When you read code, you may miss that there is assignment and not checking if something is equal to other. You should not do such assignments in if checks

Comment: Not trying to be rude but you should probably go back to a basic java tutorial because you are making pretty basic errors: 1. You declare a class within the main method and then just write code into it. That won't work in any way 2. You assign variables instead of comparing them.

Comment: consider pick one of the answer that help you

Answer (score 0):

You  only need one class (mazet or square) declare outside main method.

```
  class square {

    static boolean sides[] = new boolean[]{true, false, false, false};
    static int topx, topy, rightx, righty, downx, downy, leftx, lefty;

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        if (sides[0] = false) {
            topx = 0;
        } else {
            topx = 40;
        }

        System.out.println(topx);
    }

}
```

Comment: He has declared a class outside a main method: `public class mazet`. No idea what a class within a main method within a class is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Java is a typified language and what differentiates declaring a variable/function to not is saying its type.

Instead of saying:

```
topx = 0;
```

on declaration, you should be saying:

```
int topx = 0;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: he did declare those variables 3 lines above the assignment: `int topx,topy,rightx,righty,downx,downy,leftx,lefty;`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS you're right. Sorry for this. I'll still leave this here for future reference.